# Find record based on value from the table

Tags: c#, linq, if-statement

This is my code to find string in my UserTable.

```cs
var PhoneExists = _db.UserTable.Where(u => u.PhoneNumber == Input.PhoneNumber);
```

and this is my `if` code:

```cs
if (PhoneExists != null)
{
    ErrorAlert("number found.");
    return Page();
}
```

but every time the `if` condition is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns `true` as `PhoneExists` is not `null`, but it returns with `IQueryable` value.

You need to materialize the query to return the result queried from the database.

You may look for `.Any()` to find whether there is any record with the respective `PhoneNumber` existed.

```cs
bool PhoneExists = _db.UserTable.Any(u => u.PhoneNumber == Input.PhoneNumber);

if (PhoneExists)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Side note: Recommend to name the variable as **camelCase** following the [C# naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions#implicitly-typed-local-variables).

Answer (score 0):

`Where` will always return a non-null enumerable, and it's empty if there are no matches. You have to check its contents. If you expect the phone numbers to be unique, you could use `FirstOrDefault` or `SingleOrDefault` to return either a string, or null. The latter will, however, throw if there is more than one match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Contains** here.

Sample code:

```
var PhoneExists = _db.UserTable.Where(u => u.PhoneNumber.Contains(Input.PhoneNumber)).FirstOrDefault();
```

In your if code:

```
if (PhoneExists != null && PhoneExist.Count()== 0)
{
 ErrorAlert("number found.");
 return Page();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Exists instead of Where like this :

```
if (_db.UserTable.Exists(u => u.PhoneNumber == Input.PhoneNumber))
{
    //Do Something
}
```

About exist checkout https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.exists?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FirstOrDefault()](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.firstordefault?view=net-6.0)

```
var PhoneExists = _db.UserTable.Where(u => u.PhoneNumber == Input.PhoneNumber).FirstOrDefault();
```